# Strange Glitched Screen on Startup

Tags: boot, screen

I just ran the windows installer of Ubuntu and every boot up is accompanied by this nice

[image]

I've used the windows installer, I've made a bootable disk x32 and x64.  I've re-installed Windows to ensure it's nothing with Windows.  I've also ran Ubuntu on this machine before about a year ago.  I don't have any hardware problems.

My laptop is a ASUS G60JX.

Answer (score 0):

I use to have the same (similar?) problem after updating from 12.10 to 13.04.

These flickering lines appears straight at the log-on screen [image: Log-on]

This is what I do, to make my screen to be back in shape and colors: Right after hearing that little drum sound, enter my password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The flickering is NOT gone just yet, so I log-out. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

This how I'm again on the Log-on screen, but this time everything is fine. Log in and enjoy your Ubuntu! ;)

And this how I have to do every time I power on my laptop. My experience tells me that this could be due to video card or it's driver incapability issue. Perhaps, that's why I leave it as it is... I have ASUS A8j witch has graphics by nVidia, unfortunately...

Hope this helps in some way to you.

---

## Edit:

Is not flickering anymore (as for me). Perhaps been fixed with the latest updates... Thanks :)