# Problem with newly installed Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: display, login-screen

AMD Athlon 64x2 dual core processor 2.3 GHz
2GB RAM

I Just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on the `D:` drive which has no other data in it. Windows8 is present on the `C:` drive. Ubuntu works fine till the login page. Once I enter the password and hit go, the screen starts flickering filled with random lines of orange and brown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange Glitched Screen on Startup](http://askubuntu.com/questions/181664/strange-glitched-screen-on-startup/309791#309791).

Answer (score 0):

This was I problem I had a while back, and using propriatary drivers instead of the open-source ones bundled with Ubuntu seems to fix it.
The way I did it was repeatedly logging in and restarting till I get in and then slowly navigating to the driver page in settings, but I now read that you can press ctrl+alt+delete and then enter to get out of the glitchy screen and back to the login screen without errors when you log in again.
Anyways, after you log in, navigate to Software Sources via the dash or settings and go to the additional drivers tab to see the drivers you can use. You should look for propriatary and tested tags on the drivers to know which one you should use.

Hope this helps, Roy~

Comment: ctrl+alt+del doesnt work. in fact, the keyboard and mouse don't either. tried turning on and off caps lock! doesn't seem to work.